# Derivative of sum of functions

Tags: derivatives

If $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ are differentiable, why does,

$(s + c)' = ss' + cc' $

And not just $s' + c'$

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Are talking of chain rule? if then google it simply.

Comment: Of course $(s+c)'=s'+c'$. Are you sure it's not $\frac12 (s^2+c^2)'$?

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong, Derivative is a linear operator. It follows the following identities

$$ \begin{matrix}
  (s u)' \equiv s\, u' \\
  (u+v)' \equiv u' + v'
\end{matrix} $$

where $s$ is a scalar constant, and $u$ and $v$ are functions